# WPF MVVM: How to bind DevComponents NavigationPane?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I want to bind a DevComponents NavigationPane with PaneItems (main menu items) with ButtonDropDowns (menu items) to a property of type `List<MainMenuItems>` in the viewmodel but I dont know how to integrate the menus in the main menus.

This is how to build the menu statically:

```
<WpfRibbon:NavigationPane Width="200" LargeItemsCount="10">
    <WpfRibbon:PaneItem Header="MainMenu1">
        <StackPanel>
            <WpfRibbon:ButtonDropDown Header="Menu1"/>
            <WpfRibbon:ButtonDropDown Header="Menu2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </WpfRibbon:PaneItem>
    <WpfRibbon:PaneItem Header="MainMenu2">
        <StackPanel>
            <WpfRibbon:ButtonDropDown Header="Menu3"/>
            <WpfRibbon:ButtonDropDown Header="Menu4"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </WpfRibbon:PaneItem>
</WpfRibbon:NavigationPane>
```

Here in the data bound version I get the PaneItems rendered, but then I am stuck, I don't see how to implement the menu items (ButtonDropDowns):

```
<WpfRibbon:NavigationPane Width="200" LargeItemsCount="10"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuItems}">
    <WpfRibbon:NavigationPane.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type WpfRibbon:PaneItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}" />
        </Style>
    </WpfRibbon:NavigationPane.ItemContainerStyle>
</WpfRibbon:NavigationPane>
```

The model looks like follows:

```
MainMenuItems = new List<KisMainMenuItem>
{
    new KisMainMenuItem(title: "MainMenu1", image: @"img/books.png", menuItems: new List<KisMenuItem>
    {
        new KisMenuItem(innerTitle: "Menu1", image: @"img/books.png"),
        new KisMenuItem(innerTitle: "Menu2", image: @"img/books.png")
    }),
    new KisMainMenuItem("MainMenu2", @"img/books.png", new List<KisMenuItem>
    {
        new KisMenuItem("Menu3", @"img/books.png"),
        new KisMenuItem("Menu4", @"img/books.png")
    })
};
```

Comment: I don't know _WpfRibbon:NavigationPane_, but it seems to be some ItemsControl. Which, if true, means that you should use DataTemplates for your menu items instead of trying to bodge an ItemContainerStyle. Since the menu is hierachical (like a tree), i would expect it to be a `HeaderedItemsControl`. In which case you should probably use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (if you don't know about HierarchicalDataTemplate, see its documentation explaining it with example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

The missing part was a DataTemplate with an ItemsControl.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainMenuItem}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WpfRibbon:ButtonDropDown Header="{Binding InnerTitle}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```